# ruby on rails application couldn't find file 'jquery'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie and have seen this error a lot on here, but no solution seems to work for me.

It gives me the error Sprockets::FileNotFound in Pages#home couldn't find file 'jquery' in line 6 of application.html.erb  `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' , 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Things I've already tried:

- run new gems and require example: [couldn't find file 'jquery' in Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285873/couldnt-find-file-jquery-in-rails-project)
- clean up gemfile and asset group example: [Couldn't find file 'jquery'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567717/couldnt-find-file-jquery)
- [Couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830313/couldnt-find-file-jquery-ui)

Nothing I do seems to work.

This is my application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

This is my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Application</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> 
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' , 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

        <%= yield %>

        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

    </body>
</html>
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem "jquery-rails"
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do |variable|
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :assets do

    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

    gem 'turbolinks'

    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
    gem 'spring',        group: :development

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does `bundle install` work?

Comment: I've tried bundle install and restarted -- same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in your `application.html.erb`

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I don't see anything wrong in your Gemfile. And one thing always restart your server after running a `bundle install`.